# Drop Upon Conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to solve the following problem:
I have a dataframe. For one of the columns, I have NAN and numbers, distributed in a random fashion. I want to drop lines based on this column. My criteria is: if the line above this one and the one below have NAN as value, then I drop the line. Else, I keep the line in my data frame.

This is what I have managed to get to, but I am quite sure it is wrong... Any help is much appreciated!

```
i=0
while i <= 500:
    if (np.isnan(df.iloc[i+1]['column1'])) &  (np.isnan(df.iloc[i-1]['column1'])):
        df2[i] = df.drop(df[i])
```

Comment: Do you want to remove all the NaN and that value or just that one line and keep the NaNs? Are you going to drop all the NaNs later anyway?

Comment: I don't want to remove all the NaNs. I have merged two datasets and I am only interested in looking at the values that belong to dataset 2 and the values in dataset 1 that come imediately before and imediately after the ones in dataset 2. PS.: The datasets have different columns, so this is the reason for all the NaNs.

Answer (score 2):

Create sample data:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df= pd.DataFrame({'column1': np.random.randn(10)})
df.iloc[[2, 4, 7], 0] = np.nan
>>> df
    column1
0  1.764052
1  0.400157
2       NaN
3  2.240893   # <<< Drop.
4       NaN
5 -0.977278
6  0.950088
7       NaN
8 -0.103219
9  0.410599
```

Apply filter.

```
>>> df[~((df['column1'].shift(1).isnull()) & (df['column1'].shift(-1).isnull()))]
    column1
0  1.764052
1  0.400157
2       NaN
4       NaN
5 -0.977278
6  0.950088
7       NaN
8 -0.103219
9  0.410599
```

Comment: Not sure without seeing the data.  My guess is that the `NaN` might have been a text value instead of numpy `NaN`.  Note that if you have three consecutive`NaN` rows, it would drop the middle one per your requirement.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have found the problem. I needed an extra condition inside the logical conditions. In the end, this was the final fix: df1= df[~((df['col1'].shift(1).isnull()) & (df['col1'].shift(-1).isnull()) & (df['col1'].isnull()))]

Comment: So your condition is to drop rows where the one above is NaN, the one below is NaN, and the row itself is not NaN.

Comment: Yes, sorry! Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

**Example Data**:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":[5.43,np.nan, np.nan, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5, np.nan, 0.1, np.nan, 0.33]
})
```

You can create shifted columns and avoid looping over your dataset.

```
my_df['forward_shift'] = my_df.col1.shift(periods=1)
my_df['backward_shift'] = my_df.col1.shift(periods=-1)

out = my_df[-(np.isnan(my_df.forward_shift) & np.isnan(my_df.backward_shift))]
out['col1'].reset_index(drop=True)

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    0.5
3    0.4
4    0.5
5    NaN
6    NaN
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I tried using your method, but I got the following error: {TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''. } I think this is because all my dataframe types are objects. I don't know how to fix this...

Comment: @LauraSimonsenLeal You can could try `df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(np.float32)`.  This should change it from an object to float32.